# Invoking a method's result to the main thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, invoke

I am wondering about the following:

I have an observable collection named `Container` and method named `Method`.

On the main thread I want to add the returned value from `Method` to the `Container`.

The following code runs on another thread, so I have to Invoke the `Container.Add` to the app current thread to not have errors:

```
object obj = Method()
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
    Container.Add((MyObject)obj)
});
```

My question is if I would do the following

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
    Container.Add((MyObject)Method())
});
```

The method (which is a long running method) will run on the app current thread, which is not quite correct because it will hand the UI, could I invoke only the returned value of the method to be added to the `Container` without defining the object like in the first example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [this Invoke overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647509(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<MyObject>(o => Container.Add(o)), (MyObject)Method());
```

You may however get rid of the background thread and call Method in a `Task`. Thus you would avoid the need to call Dispatcher.Invoke:

```
Container.Add(await Task.Run(() => (MyObject)Method()));
```

Comment: Wouldn't the second option require the calling method to be marked as `async`?

Comment: @Grx70 Sure, as usual.

Comment: So using the first example, Method would be executed on the same thread but the result will be only invoked to the UI thread?

Comment: "invoke a result" is a term that doesn't make much sense. The method is called on the background thread, then the result (an object reference) is passed to the UI thread as argument to Invoke.

Comment: yes but there is already a new thread spawned, this will create another, in this case I think the second solution is the better one.

Comment: No, this (the first example) will not create a thread. You are already in a background thread. Calling Invoke will just execute the Action on the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to @Clemens' proposal, you can use [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap):

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
{
    Container.Add(await Task.Run(() => Method()));
});
```

Note though that this requires either *.NET 4.5* or later, or *.NET 4* together with [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) NuGet package.

Comment: Now you wouldn't need to call Dispatcher.Invoke anymore, because there wouldn't be any background thread.

Comment: @Clemens You would if this code is executed on a thread other than UI thread (which judging from the question it is). I agree however that `Method` will be executed on yet another thread, and it isn't the best solution in terms of simply getting rid of a variable.

Comment: If there was a thread other than the UI thread, you wouldn't need to call Method in a Task. You are already in a background thread then.